# TypeError: Type is not callable - on compile

Tags: solidity, fallback

I have created a game where I have an interface and a contract with a Game function
But when I compile it throws an exception:

**TypeError: Type is not callable
myGameContract.depositPlayer(0, msg.value)();**

It is clear that it refers to the fallback after: msg.value)**();**

But, I don't know how to fix the interface.

```
interface Game{
    function depositPlayer(uint256 _pid, uint256 _amount) external payable;

function myGame(address _reciever) external payable {
    addressBoard = payable(_reciever);
    myGameContract= Game(addressBoard );
    myGameContract.depositPlayer(0, msg.value)();
```

I need in this case it to contain a fallback
**();**

More bellow:

> For more clarification, comment as the answer indicates, only the call
> function contains a fallback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute an external function without the empty parentheses.

Example that executes the external `depositPlayer` function:

```
myGameContract.depositPlayer(0, msg.value);  // removed the `()`
```

---

You can execute the `fallback` function by sending an empty `data` field.

```
address(myGameContract).call("");
```

But the fallback function is executed when no suitable function (specified in the `data` field) is found. It's not executed after each function. So you can't execute both `depositPlayer` and `fallback` in the same call (except for executing `depositPlayer` from the `fallback`).

Comment: I know, but I have a fallback function, which executes other code, it is imperative that it is

Comment: @Cazs So you want to execute just the fallback function (without the `0` and `msg.value` params)? Or can you describe what is the reason behind including the params in the question?

Comment: The intention in the backup function, is to keep an external counter in the main contract, I had thought in the interface to add a return fallback, but I don't know how to do it in solidity

Comment: @Cazs The fallback function is not executed "after each function", it's executed "instead of throwing an error for trying to execute a non-existing function". I edited my answer with example how to call the fallback function... Hope this helps.

Comment: @Thanks for throwing another answer.
After much reading, I have come to "understand" that only call has a fallback.
If it is about invoking a function defined from the interface, it cannot be done.
I have changed my logic, so that it is through the call function

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy error to make when you accidentally make an argument shadow a function. Here's an easy to understand place this error would pop up:

```
 constructor(address owner, address[] memory defaultOperators) ERC777("Shipyard", "SHIP", defaultOperators) {
        transferOwnership(owner);
        ico = address(new ShipICO(this));
        _mint(owner(), INITIAL_SUPPLY, "", "");
        _pause();
    }
```

Note that the argument `owner` has the same name as the function called in the `_mint(owner())` line. Because of the argument having the same name, you're now trying to call the argument `owner`, which is of type `address`, as if it were a `function`. (Note that in this case, `owner()` is a function inherited from the OZ `Ownable` contract, making it especially easy to miss.

Easy, common convention is to add an underscore. In this case, `_owner` may already be taken, so you may add an underscore to the end (`owner_` ) for the argument.

As to the OP's question:

This means that `myGameContract.depositPlayer` is not a function. Go figure out why you think it is, and the compiler thinks it isn't.